# How can I close my FriendFeed account?

Tags: facebook, friendfeed

I started a FriendFeed account from Facebook and now I neither know my FriendFeed email address nor have kept my Facebook account. How can I terminate my FriendFeed account that's still there publicly? I know my username at FriendFeed but their support doesn't answer questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct removal link is this: http://friendfeed.com/account/delete

> If you wish to terminate your FriendFeed account, you can do so at: http://friendfeed.com/account/delete. You can also write to us at FriendFeed Inc., 313 W. Evelyn Ave., Mountain View, CA 94041. If you terminate your account, your profile and any entries or comments you’ve made will be removed from the site. Your account will be deleted immediately, but it will remain in our backup systems.

[Source](http://friendfeed.com/about/privacy) (under *Choices for personal information*).

> Publicly visible text/images often aren't properly deleted even when you succeed in deleting an account. Try editing or deleting them manually before deleting the account itself. If you're unsure what happens to your tracks: this can be found mostly in the Terms of Service/Privacy Policy; otherwise you can always contact FriendFeed and ask personally. By the way, deletion requests don't necessarily mean your data will actually be deleted (e.g. due to legal obligations).

Also,

> If you signed up for FriendFeed using a third-party login such as Facebook or Twitter, you probably want to revoke all access from FriendFeed.

[Source](http://www.accountkiller.com/en/delete-friendfeed-account).